Snowflake Python Connector: EOF issue when send queries to run
I have this type of SQL script inside my file "file.sql"
USE SCHEMA "CCM";

-- create table and insert a single row
DECLARE 
   l_QUERY VARCHAR(8000);
BEGIN
    -- Create table if not exists
    l_QUERY := 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_declare_table
                (
                STUDENTID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
                FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(16777216) NOT NULL,
                LASTNAME VARCHAR(16777216) NOT NULL,
                AGE NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL
                )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_QUERY;

    -- Insert a single row with fixed values
    l_QUERY := 'INSERT INTO test_declare_table (STUDENTID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE) VALUES (1, ''John'', ''Doe'', 30)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_QUERY;
END;

Then I have this Python function that I use to decode the file and deploy (sent the query to run in Snowflake):
def decode_sql_script(self,  script_path):
        encodings_to_try = ['utf-8','utf-8-sig','utf-16le','utf-16be','utf-16','utf-16-sig','utf-32le','utf-32be','iso-8859-1','cp1252','ascii', 'latin-1']
        
        with open(script_path, 'rb') as sql_file:
            sql_content = sql_file.read().strip()
            for encoding in encodings_to_try:
                print(encoding)
                try:
                    decoded_sql = sql_content.decode(encoding)
                    print(f"Prepared Script to be executed : {decoded_sql}") # if not error script decode ok
                    return decoded_sql
                    #cursors = conn.execute_string(decoded_sql)

                except Exception as e: 
                    self.sql_errors.append(f"{encoding} error: {e}")
                    continue
        for conn in self.connections:
            conn.rollback()
            conn.close()
        print("Transaction rolled back due to script error.")
        #sys.exit(1)
        raise ValueError("Failed to decode SQL file with supported encodings.")

and the deploy function:
 def deploy_scripts(self):
        # Define query tag based on the environment
        if self.env == "prd":
            query_tag = "Change Request: " + self.change_request_num
        else:
            query_tag = "Deployment Request: " + self.deployment_request_id
        
        status = []  # List to store deployment status
        
        # Connect to Snowflake
        conn = self.connect_to_snowflake(self.script_details)
        self.connections.append(conn)
        
        try:
            # Iterate over each script
            for script in self.script_details['scripts']:
                script_path = os.path.join(self.repo_root_dir, "SnowflakeCICDFramework", "Stage", self.deployment_request_id, self.env.upper(), self.repo_base_path, self.read_database_name, script) # read from stage 
                print(f"Executing Script: {script}")
                
                try:
                    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                        cursor.execute(f"ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG = '{query_tag}'")
                        decoded_sql = self.decode_sql_script(script_path)
                        cursors = conn.execute_string(decoded_sql)
                        
                        # Iterate over each query in the script
                        for cursor in cursors:
                            query_id = cursor.sfqid
                            print(f"\tExecuting Query ID: {query_id}")
                            
                            while True:
                                query_status = conn.get_query_status(query_id)
                                if conn.is_still_running(query_status):
                                    print(f"Query {query_id} is still running...")
                                    time.sleep(5)  # Sleep for 5 seconds before checking again
                                    continue

The issue for this type of request is that my code is not sending correctly the block to run because should run "use schema;" which does and is ok
then the entire DECLARE ... "END;" block to run as 1
because the error I get is:

which comes because my script is trying to sent to snowflake to run:
DECLARE 
   l_QUERY VARCHAR(8000);

by himself.
Any ideas? I tried to use and sent pl/sql entire block but I get "give 2 to run, expected 1".
I tried to make a possibility to send the entire script as string to run like the entire content in the file, but didn't work.

What if you wrapped the multi-line script section in an execute immediate and used $$ to wrap the code?  Does that help?

hmm.. i get now "Stored Procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started i nstored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back"

very strange, because the dynamic sql`s inside are being executed then the entire "execute immediate $$ ....my query $$; fails

This is a known error by Snowflake. Please try to remove single line comments at your sql definition:
-- create table and insert a single row  ext.
Please see this link for more explanation
